# What's wrong with this Set-Cookie header?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, setcookie

I have an ASP.NET MVC project under development in VS 2013 and running on localhost.  A cookie is sent with the

```
Set-Cookie: Tx=88440; expires=Sun, 03 Apr 2016 12:49:28 GMT; domain=localhost; path=/
```

Chrome receives this ok.  But when I refreshes the page in Chrome, the cookie Tx is not sent back to the server.  Is there anything wrong with the cookie header?  Does a path of / mean it will apply to all paths beneath /?

Comment: I think I found the cause.  The domain isn't right.  If I don't set the domain at the server, it is not included, and Chrome sends it back on the next request.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome ignores localhost for cookies. Design decision apparently.